# Complement of a set is not a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does one prove that for all sets S, there is no set T that contains all x not in S? This is working in ZFC, of course.

Comment: If there were, we could union S and T to get a universal set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If such a set $T$ existed, then the collection $V$ of all sets would be a set by the union axiom, as $V=T\cup S$. But $V$ is known to be a proper class and not a set (see Russell's paradox), hence no such set $T$ is allowed to exist.

Comment: To define a complement using ZF you have to use the separation axiom and define $U-S=\{x\in U:x\not \in S\}$. The complement is not well defined because of what Marco said.

Comment: @jiyanez, that doesn't prove that complements don't exist, it just shows that the naive strategy for proving they exist doesn't work.

Comment: I know. The proof for that was given by Marco. I'm just saying how can you define the notion of complement that we use in general.